How to remove malicious OS build on Samsung Galaxy S24?
How do I remove malicious OS build on Samsung Galaxy S24?
Phone won't let me remove malicious software and all scans from multiple sources get directed to emulated files. Factory reset reinstalled all lib files on gradle and restricts opening any software or tools I could use to fix this problem.
What should I do?
Software information
One UI version 6.1
Android version 14
Google Play system update August 1, 2024
Baseband version S928USQU3AXH7
Kernel version 6.1.57-android14-11-29543898-abS928USQU3AXH7 #1 Fri Aug 16 08:31:05 UTC 2024
Build number UP1A.231005.007.S928USQU3AXH7
SE for Android status Enforcing SEPF_SM-S928U_14_0001 Fri Aug 16 17:48:02 2024
Knox version Knox 3.10 Knox API level 37 Knox ML 1.4 DualDAR 1.6.0 HDM 2.0 - 1D
Service provider software version SAOMC_SM-S928U_OYN_TMB_14 0026 TMB/TMB,TMB/XAU/TMB
Carrier configuration version 4.0000
Security software version MDF v3.3 Release 1 BT v1.0 Release 1 WLAN v1.0 Release 2 VPN Client v2.4 Release 2.0 ASKS v8.1 Release 20230714 ADP v3.1 Release 20230510 FIPS BoringSSL v1.7 FIPS SKC v2.3 FIPS SCrypto v2.7 SMR Aug-2024 Release 1
Android security patch level August 1, 2024
GPU Version OpenGL ES 3.2 V@0744.18 (GIT@d774a8672e, 18ea610b5b4, 1704277645)

Why do you think your OS is malicious? By default the bootloader is locked and verified boot is active which means the system partition is signed and can not be modified.

I’m voting to close this question because it is not about reverse engineering.  It's more like technical support.
